# Recognizing an operation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Deﬁne an operation $\alpha:\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ by $\langle v_1, v_2\rangle$ $\alpha \langle u_1, u_2\rangle=\langle v_1u_1 −v_2u_2,v_1u_2 + v_2u_1\rangle$.

Do you recognize this product? i.e. where does it come from/is it a real operation or a derivative of one?

What I tried:

I found that it was a form of the cross product defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ but was not sure how to form it exactly. I tried to make $\mathbb{R}^3$ vectors out of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ by repeating one of their components to make the third components and then take the cross product and truncating the third component. That didn't work out to well. Ideas?

Comment: in terms of product of complex numbers is similar to $(a+bi)(c+di)=ac-bd+(ad+bc)i$

Comment: This should give you a way to answer your previous questions, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(u_1,u_2),(v_1,v_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and let define: $$z_1:=u_1+iu_2\textrm{ and }z_2:=v_1+iv_2.$$
Then: $$z_1z_2=(u_1v_1-u_2v_2)+i(u_1v_2+u_2v_1).$$
Hence, $\alpha$ is the complex multiplication *via* the identification $\mathbb{R}^2\cong\mathbb{C},(x,y)\mapsto x+iy$.